# In the new Kafka Consumer API versions >0.9 what property replaces consumer.timeout.ms?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I cannot figure out from the documentation which property now replaces consumer.timeout.ms =-1 (Default) which was available in Kafka Consumer API versions before 0.9. Does anyone have the link to the new documentation?

I Looked for Kafka documentation but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious counterpart in java consumer, since the new consumer is non-blocking. In Scala consumer, this config controls whether the consumer iterators are blocking. By default, they are blocking. If the value for this config is set to be larger than zero, they turn to be non-blocking. Unlike returning empty record set like `poll` in new consumer, the old consumer throws an exception when the waiting time elapses before any records are fetched.

If you still want to figure out a replacement, I think it'll be the timeout parameter in KafkaConsumer.poll method. However, like what I said above, poll does not throw exceptions when timeout is hit.